# Не запускается sphinx в контейнере docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sphinx

Сразу скажу, что я новичок в docker. Возникла проблема с запуском Sphinx. При запуске контейнера он сразу завершает свою работу.

```
        Name                      Command               State                Ports             
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
project_db_1           docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp        
project_phpmyadmin_1   /run.sh phpmyadmin               Up       0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp, 9000/tcp
project_sphinx_1       /bin/bash -c /run.sh             Exit 1                                 
project_www_1          docker-php-entrypoint apac ...   Up       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
```

Лог из контейнера:

```
precaching index 'groups'
WARNING: index 'groups': preload: failed to open /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx/test3.sph: No such file or directory; NOT SERVING
precaching index 'materials'
WARNING: index 'materials': preload: failed to open /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx/test2.sph: No such file or directory; NOT SERVING
precaching index 'positionKSR'
WARNING: index 'positionKSR': preload: failed to open /etc/sphinxsearch/test1.sph: No such file or directory; NOT SERVING
FATAL: no valid indexes to serve
```

Насколько я понимаю необходимо запустить indexer чтобы проиндексировать таблицы. Я пробовал добавить к файлу docker-compose команду на индекс, однако тогда в логфайл идет запись о том, что я неправильно использую indexer.

Докеркомпоз-файл:

```
 sphinx:
        image: rpowered/sphinxsearch
        command: indexer --rotate --all
        volumes:
            - ./docker/sphinx/conf/sphinx.conf:/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf
            #- ./docker/sphinx/data/diz:/var/diz/sphinx
            #- ./docker/sphinx/data/run:/var/run/sphinx
            #- ./docker/sphinx/data/lib:/var/lib/sphinx
            #- ./docker/sphinx/data/log:/var/log/sphinx
            #- ./docker/sphinx/data/idx:/var/idx/sphinx
```

Лог из контейнера:

```
Sphinx 2.2.11-id64-release (95ae9a6)
Copyright (c) 2001-2016, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

Usage: indexer [OPTIONS] [indexname1 [indexname2 [...]]]

Options are:
--config <file>         read configuration from specified file
                        (default is sphinx.conf)
--all                   reindex all configured indexes
--quiet                 be quiet, only print errors
--verbose               verbose indexing issues report
--noprogress            do not display progress
                        (automatically on if output is not to a tty)
--rotate                send SIGHUP to searchd when indexing is over
                        to rotate updated indexes automatically
--sighup-each           send SIGHUP to searchd after each index
                        (used with --rotate only)
--buildstops <output.txt> <N>
                        build top N stopwords and write them to given file
--buildfreqs            store words frequencies to output.txt
                        (used with --buildstops only)
--merge <dst-index> <src-index>
                        merge 'src-index' into 'dst-index'
                        'dst-index' will receive merge result
                        'src-index' will not be modified
--merge-dst-range <attr> <min> <max>
                        filter 'dst-index' on merge, keep only those documents
                        where 'attr' is between 'min' and 'max' (inclusive)
--merge-klists
--merge-killlists       merge src and dst k-lists (default is to discard them
                        after merge; note that src k-list applies anyway)
--dump-rows <FILE>      dump indexed rows into FILE
--print-queries         print SQL queries (for debugging)
--keep-attrs            retain attributes from the old index
Examples:
indexer --quiet myidx1  reindex 'myidx1' defined in 'sphinx.conf'
indexer --all           reindex all indexes defined in 'sphinx.conf'
```

Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам не принципиален именно Sphinx, то Manticore (форк Sphinx) запускается в докер нормально - https://hub.docker.com/r/manticoresearch/manticore/
Инструкция здесь https://docs.manticoresearch.com/latest/html/getting-started/docker.html

Возможная проблема с вашим docker compose файлом в том, что вы не указали путь до конфига в команде индексации и по дефолтному пути он, возможно, тоже не находится.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Manticore дает тот же самый результат. Файлы индексов просто напросто не создаются...

Comment: @Viktor А вы делали все по инструкции https://docs.manticoresearch.com/latest/html/getting-started/docker.html ?

Comment: судя по всему проблема в моем sphinx.conf со стандартным индекс создается успешно

Comment: rt индексы создаются нормально, а вот plain никак не хотят

Comment: решил проблему добавив к docker-compose следующую команду: "command: /usr/bin/indexer --all" файлы индексов создались, однако контейнер сразу после индексации завершает свою работу.